# Group by zipcode and year, and cumsum by specific condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My dataset contains houses (id), whether they are a rental property (rental) and which year they installed solar power, denoted by the columns year and solar power. I want to aggregate this data by zipcode and year, and cumsum the total solar_power in the area for the rental properties.

```
#generate data
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1202, 1202, 1231, 1231, 1412, 1412),
  zip = c("zip2", "zip2", "zip1", "zip1", "zip2", "zip2"),
  year = c(2016, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2017),
  solar_power = c(0, 0, 0, 400, 500,500),
  rental = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
  )

#I tried the following but did not give desired result
grouped <- df %>%
  group_by(zip, year) %>%
  summarise(cumsum_power = ifelse(rental==1, cumsum(solar_power), solar_power))
```

| zip | year | solar_power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| zip1 | 2016 | 0 |
| zip1 | 2017 | 400 |
| zip2 | 2016 | 0 |
| zip2 | 2017 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

`cumsum()` would fit in here if `year` is not part of your grouping, and you'd be mutating, not summarising, for example. But right now you seem to ask for `sum(rental * solar_power)` :

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1202, 1202, 1231, 1231, 1412, 1412),
  zip = c("zip2", "zip2", "zip1", "zip1", "zip2", "zip2"),
  year = c(2016, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2017),
  solar_power = c(0, 0, 0, 400, 500,500),
  rental = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
)

df %>%
  group_by(zip, year) %>%
  summarise(power_sum_rental = sum(rental * solar_power))           
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'zip'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   zip [2]
#>   zip    year power_sum_rental
#>   <chr> <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 zip1   2016                0
#> 2 zip1   2017              400
#> 3 zip2   2016                0
#> 4 zip2   2017                0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found, as shown below:

```
# Create a data frame with all combinations of zip and year
all_combinations <- expand.grid(zip = unique(df$zip), year = unique(df$year))

# Group by zip and year, and calculate the cumulative sum of solar_power for rentals
result <- df %>%
  filter(rental == 0) %>%
  group_by(zip, year) %>%
  summarise(cumulative_solar_power = cumsum(solar_power),
            total_koop = n()) %>%
  right_join(all_combinations, by = c("zip", "year")) %>%
  mutate(cumulative_solar_power = ifelse(is.na(cumulative_solar_power), 0, cumulative_solar_power))
```